# How to unpack tupled list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have tupled list like this.

```
[('"ram', '18"'), ('"kp', '12"'), ('"nm', '14"')]
```

How to unpack this to get the result like below.

```
ram,18
kp,12
nm,14
```

Thanks.

Comment: Refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839168/extracting-information-from-a-tuple-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839168/extracting-information-from-a-tuple-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over the list to unpack each piece.

```
mylist = [('"ram', '18"'), ('"kp', '12"'), ('"nm', '14"')]
for tup in mylist:
  print ",".join(tup)
```

Output:

```
"ram,18"
"kp,12"
"nm,14"
```

If you do not like the quotes, just remove them after the join.

```
for tup in mylist:
  print ",".join(tup).replace('"','')
```

Output:

```
ram,18
kp,12
nm,14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ta = [('"ram', '18"'), ('"kp', '12"'), ('"nm', '14"')]
for t in ta:
    print ','.join(t)
```

or you can access individual items by indexing them:

```
ta[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `for` loop should be enough.

Eg:

```
items = [('ram', '18'), ('kp', '12'), ('nm', '14')]

for label, value in items:
    print label + "," + value
```